# How to iterate over points in the exterior ring of a geos::Polygon in rust

Tags: rust, geos

I have a geometry representing a polygon, I want to iterate of the points in the exterior ring. I tried following the same approach as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017295/iterate-over-points-in-geos-polygon-using-c-api) but it doesn't seem to work in rust.

The `get_exterior_ring` function returns a `ConstGeometry` of type `LinearRing`. If I  call `get_num_points` on this geometry it returns an error

```
 Err(
    GenericError(
        "Geometry must be a LineString",
    ),
)
```

```rust
let test_polygon: Polygon = Polygon::new(
  LineString(vec![
    Coord::from((4.9147899, 52.3735245)),
    Coord::from((4.9148563, 52.3735048)),
    Coord::from((4.9148865, 52.3735437)),
    Coord::from((4.9148248, 52.3735613)),
    Coord::from((4.9147899, 52.3735245)),
  ]),
  vec![LineString(vec![])],
);
let geometry: geos::Geometry = (&test_polygon).try_into().unwrap();
let linear_ring: ConstGeometry  = geometry.get_exterior_ring().unwrap();
dbg!(linear_ring.get_num_points().err());
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://github.com/georust/geos/issues/132

```
use geos::{ConstGeometry, CoordSeq, Geom};

let test_polygon: Polygon = Polygon::new(
    LineString(vec![
        Coord::from((4.9147899, 52.3735245)),
        Coord::from((4.9148563, 52.3735048)),
        Coord::from((4.9148865, 52.3735437)),
        Coord::from((4.9148248, 52.3735613)),
        Coord::from((4.9147899, 52.3735245)),
    ]),
    vec![LineString(vec![])],
);
let geometry: geos::Geometry = (&test_polygon).try_into().unwrap();
let linear_ring: ConstGeometry  = geometry.get_exterior_ring().unwrap();
let coord_seq: CoordSeq = linear_ring.get_coord_seq().unwrap();

let size = coord_seq.size().unwrap();
println!("coord_seq size: {}", size);

for i in 0..size {
    let (x, y) = (coord_seq.get_x(i).unwrap(), coord_seq.get_y(i).unwrap());
    println!("coord of point n°{}: {:?}", i, (x, y));
}
```